# Picture changing in vb6

Tags: vb6

I was trying this script from a pdf file.I got stuck where the target image should change to exploding image if clicked but the target image does not change from the standing image.Please Help!

```
Option Explicit

Dim fiPlayersScore As Integer
Dim fiNumberofMisses As Integer
Dim fbTargetHit As Boolean
Private Sub Form_Load()
Randomize
imgTarget.Enabled = False
imgTarget.Visible = False
cmdStop.Enabled = False
lblGameOver.Visible = False
lblGameOver.Enabled = False
End Sub
Private Sub cmdStart_Click()
Dim lsUserResponse As String
Dim lbResponse As Boolean

lsUserResponse = InputBox("Enter a level from 1 to 3." & _
(Chr(13)) & "" & (Chr(13)) & "1 being  the Easiest and 3 being the " & _
"Hardest.", "Level Select", "1")
lbResponse = False
If lsUserResponse = "1" Then
Timer1.Interval = 1500
lbResponse = True
ElseIf lsUserResponse = "2" Then
Timer1.Interval = 1000
lbResponse = True
ElseIf lsUserResponse = "3" Then
Timer1.Interval = 750
lbResponse = True
Else
MsgBox ("Game Not Started.")
lbResponse = False
End If
If lbResponse = True Then
cmdStart.Enabled = False
imgTarget.Picture = imgStanding.Picture 

frmMain.MousePointer = 5
fbTargetHit = False
Load_Sounds
cmdStop.Enabled = True
fiPlayersScore = 0
fiNumberofMisses = 0
lblScore.Caption = fiPlayersScore
lblMisses.Caption = fiNumberofMisses
Timer1.Enabled = True
lblGameOver.Visible = False
lblGameOver.Enabled = False
End If
End Sub

Private Sub cmdStop_Click()
Unload_Sounds
frmMain.MousePointer = vbNormal
Timer1.Enabled = False
imgTarget.Enabled = False
imgTarget.Visible = False
cmdStart.Enabled = True
cmdStop.Enabled = False
cmdStart.SetFocus
lblGameOver.Visible = True
lblGameOver.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Click()
MMControl1.Command = "Play"
MMControl1.Command = "Prev"
fiNumberofMisses = fiNumberofMisses + 1
lblMisses.Caption = fiNumberofMisses
If CheckForLoose = True Then
cmdStop_Click
lblMisses.Caption = fiNumberofMisses
Exit Sub
End If
End Sub

Private Sub imgTarget_Click()
MMControl2.Command = "Play"
MMControl2.Command = "Prev"
Timer1.Enabled = False
imgTarget.Picture = imgExplode.Picture '**I AM STUCK HERE**
pauseProgram

fiPlayersScore = fiPlayersScore + 1
Timer1.Enabled = True
If CheckForWin = True Then
cmdStop_Click
lblScore.Caption = fiPlayersScore
Exit Sub
End If
lblScore.Caption = fiPlayersScore
fbTargetHit = True
imgStanding.Enabled = False
imgTarget.Visible = False
imgTarget.Enabled = False
Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub
Public Sub Load_Sounds()
'Set initial property values for blaster sound
MMControl1.Notify = False
MMControl1.Wait = True
MMControl1.Shareable = False
MMControl1.DeviceType = "WaveAudio"
MMControl1.FileName = _
"C:\Temp\Sounds\Blaster_1.wav"
'Open the media device
 MMControl1.Command = "Open"

 Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
 Dim liRandomLeft As Integer
 Dim liRandomTop As Integer
 imgTarget.Visible = True
 If fbTargetHit = True Then
 fbTargetHit = False
 imgTarget.Picture = imgStanding.Picture
 End If
 liRandomLeft = (6120 * Rnd)
 liRandomTop = (4680 * Rnd)
 imgTarget.Left = liRandomLeft
 imgTarget.Top = liRandomTop
 imgTarget.Enabled = True
 imgTarget.Visible = True
 End Sub

 Public Function CheckForWin() As Boolean
 CheckForWin = False
 If fiPlayersScore = 5 Then
 CheckForWin = True
 lblGameOver.Caption = "You Win.Game Over"
 End If
 End Function
 Public Function CheckForLoose() As Boolean
 CheckForLoose = False
 If fiNumberofMisses = 5 Then
 CheckForLoose = True
 lblGameOver.Caption = "You Loose.Game Over"
 End If
 End Function

Private Sub Form_QueryUnload(Cancel As Integer, _
UnloadMode As Integer)
Unload_Sounds
End Sub
Public Sub Unload_Sounds()
MMControl1.Command = "Close"
MMControl2.Command = "Close"
End Sub
Public Sub pauseProgram()
Dim currentTime
Dim newTime
currentTime = Second(Time)
newTime = Second(Time)
Do Until Abs(newTime - currentTime) >= 1
newTime = Second(Time)
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

```
imgTarget.Picture = imgExplode.Picture
imgTarget.Refresh
```

Comment: that is for multiple images and auto loading with timer

Comment: Why not just load a new image from the image list on your click event.

Comment: I can not find the image list control

Comment: To add the ImageList control to your VB project, 
click Project|Components, 
and check the box next to Microsoft Windows Common Controls

Comment: thanks after search on google I got how to add the imagelist control.on running the script error message is m_index variable not defined.So I added in the start
       Private m_Index As Integer
       Private m_NumImages As Integer
and in the  Private Sub imgTarget_Click()
       m_Index = ((m_Index + 1) Mod m_NumImages) + 1
       imgTarget.Picture = ImageList1.ListImages(m_Index).Picture
but the result is the same as before

Comment: Thanks RenicK.It worked.Actually imagelist was not required.Just adding imgTarget.refresh immediately after imgTarget.Picture=imgExplode.Picture did the job.Unfortunately I cannot add a tick mark to your valuable help as you have answered in comment.Please post in answer question so I can tick your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note:

```
Set imgTarget.Picture = imgExplode.Picture
imgTarget.Refresh
```

will be faster than

```
imgTarget.Picture = imgExplode.Picture
imgTarget.Refresh
```

if imgExplode is going to be around during the lifetime of imgTarget (the first command copies the image, the Set command references the image).

Comment: Sorry Kris, slightly late in answering the question